# Как прочитать консоль Windows

Tags: windows, delphi, вывод, консоль

Как после выполнения команды *Windows* (из приложения *Delphi*) прочитать текст из консоли *Windows*.

Например после выполнения команды "help" причитать текст выводимой данной командой

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут пишут как [Opening a TStream on stdin/stdout in a Delphi console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060591/opening-a-tstream-on-stdin-stdout-in-a-delphi-console-app)

Answer (score 0):

Как правило консольные приложения пишут в STDOUT или в STDERR. Присоедините STDIN Вашей программы к стандартным потокам той программы, которая Вам интересна

Comment: Теоретическая часть мне известна. Мне нужен пример кода на Delphi